# How to check browser compatability easily

Tags: web, cross-browser

Is there something out there that will let me see how a webpage will look in all major browsers all at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Browser Shots](http://browsershots.org/) seems to cover just about all OS and browser options. it takes screen shots to show you how it looks